# Suddenly no sound

Tags: sound, 16.04

My sound stopped working just from doing nothing. I was afk for about two hours and when I came back there simply was no sound. Restarted my system several times. When using `speaker-test` on my headphones I get the following error: `Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy` I asked google and tried some guides but couldn't find any solution. My sound is definitely not muted in the alsamixer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this I had to go into the `alsamixer` and switch the analog output from "Stereo Headphones FP" to "Stereo Headphones".

Answer (score 1):

I facing a problem is, when playing video in the half way. Suddenly turn off my volume, but after i check it all is not mute.
I try to go into alsamixer and disable the "Auto-mute" function. Now so far is all work fine for me! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If you tried all of the other options available, try restarting the desktop manager(thereby the login session, user-settings, etc). In my case, I did alsa force-load, killall pulseaudio, removed pulseaudio config files, etc, selected proper soundcard, etc - didn't fix. I didn't want reboot just to get sound back. So, I knew restarting lightdm(desktop manager in my case) would work as in many other cases. So, below is the command I ran, logged in and volia, the sound is back!

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: It worked for me. However, it is a temporary solution which is better than to restart the system or re-install `alsa` and `pulseaudio`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I didn't find a permanent solution in this purpose except than a temporary solution which solves my no sound problem through restarting the *pulseaudio/ALSA* services:

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```