# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: sound

I searched for similar questions but didn't find a solution for my problem.
I have a Samsung laptop (NP300) that worked perfectly with windows 10. Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to get used to it, but since I have Ubuntu there is no sound from the computer. Not from music, neither movies nor youtube. I tried system settings/sound, the check doesn't do anything. I tried the 'alasmixer' but still didn't change anything. Can someone help?

Comment: I'll add  some information: I tried installing pulseaudio and playing with the equalizer, still no sucsess. However I found out the earphones do work and i get perfect sound through them... So it must be somthing with the speakers - maby the system doesn't recognize them?

Comment: [I've posted an answer in another question post.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240841/772449)

Comment: After searching for the solution on umpteen websites, I found the solution here,
https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-no-sound-on-upgrade-18-04-20-04-only-have-dumthe-output/
Run these commands, sudo apt-get install timidity-daemon. And then, sudo apt purge timidity-daemon

Answer (score 4):

-Open a terminal and type
`alsamixer`

-Check that all sounds are correctly set and you are setting it for the correct audio device.

-Go to sound settings and press the **test button**. Though it might not work for you but it strangely worked for me.

You may [visit this link](https://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/) for more detailed troubleshooting.

Comment: I tried it, I also disabled the 'auto-mute' option, but the test still doesn't give a sound...

Comment: It might be a hardware problem. Is sound being played in any other operating system?

Comment: Yes. In windows 10 it works fine.

Comment: I have added a link to my answer. Please upvote my answer if it helps.

Comment: Tried this method on ubuntu 16.04.1 and linuxmint 18.1 but didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Use `pavucontrol` and the check all the settings. In particular go to the `Configuration` tab and change the values from the drop list.

The correct selected item should be `Analog Stereo Duplex`.

Answer (score 1):

Run commands below:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

then reboot your system.

Comment: `apt-get remove --purge alsa-base` removes ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-gnome-desktop together

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Since the sound is working in Windows, it may be a driver issue. Check whether the hardware is detected properly (All Settings -> Sound -> Output). Furthermore, you could try whether sound is working with Ubuntu 14.04 or 17.04 with a live stick.

If this does not help, it would be best to use the official sound troubleshooting advices from ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure (especially I'd suggest to try to restart pulseaudio).

Answer (score 0):

For 'dummy output' issue.

Before performing mixer reinstall or upgrade, check your audio output status in BIOS.